# Difference on Inverse Fourier Transform beetween R and Scala Breeze

Tags: r, scala, scala-breeze

I'm trying to convert R code into scala, and i notice a difference beetween breeze and R when i perform an inverse fourier transform. ( fft in R ; inverseFourierTransform in breeze ).

In Scala Breeze

```
val vec = new DenseVector(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
val res = inverseFourierTransform(vec)

// res = ( 2.5 ; -0.5 - 0.5i ; -0.5 ; -0.5 + 0.5i )
```

In R

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4)
res <- fft(vec, inverse = TRUE)

# res = ( 10 ; -2 - 2i ; -2 ; -2 + 2i )
```

We can observe a difference by a factor 4 beetween two results

Where did she come from ?

Comment: It should be `fft(vec, inverse=TRUE) / length(vec)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the help file of `fft`, the inverse should be calculated with:

```
fft(x, inverse = TRUE)/length(x)
```

So in your case:

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4)
res <- fft(vec, inverse = TRUE)/length(vec)
res
# [1]  2.5+0.0i -0.5-0.5i -0.5+0.0i -0.5+0.5i
```

Or using `pracma` package:

```
pracma::ifft(vec)
# [1]  2.5+0.0i -0.5-0.5i -0.5+0.0i -0.5+0.5i
```

A note in `ifft` help page specifies that it is *Almost an alias for R's fft(x, inverse=TRUE), but dividing by length(x)*